# Knockout with SharePoint 2013 makes permanent changes to my DOM

Tags: knockout.js, sharepoint-2013

I am extremely new to SharePoint, but I have experience with Knockout.  I've set up a page that runs all of my code just fine.  I look at the page in the browser and things are great.  When I go to Edit Page, everything is fine, but when I'm done editing, all of my Knockout foreach bindings have multiplied and I have a lot more elements on the page.  If I sit on the Edit Page page, after a while the Knockout bindings will be reevaluated and I can watch the new elements be added to the page.  In addition, if I go into SharePoint Designer and look at the code for the page, all of those elements are now actually in the code.

The code in my Content Editor Web Part is as follows:

```
<div id="vcmContainer">
    <div id="contentHead" data-bind="foreach: Processes">
        <div class="column process">
            <div class="header">
                <!-- ko if: $index() > 0 -->
                <div class="divider"></div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
            </div>
        </div>              
    </div>
    <div id="contentBody" data-bind="foreach: Processes">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="contentTypes" data-bind="foreach: contentTypes">
                <div class="contentType">
                    <span data-bind="text: contentType"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="/SiteAssets/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="/SiteAssets/Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.js"></script> 
<script src="/SiteAssets/Scripts/ko.sp-1.0.min.Ex.js"></script> 
<script src="/SiteAssets/Scripts/script.js"></script>
```

Here is the css:

```
#vcmContainer{
    background-color: #0099CC;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
}

#contentHead{
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

#contentBody .column {
    border-left: 2px solid white;
}           
#contentBody .column:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}

.column{
    width: 8%;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.process{
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height:50px;
    height:50px;
}

.divider{
    min-width: 20px; /*change later when images are swapped out*/
    width: 7%;
    height:50px;
    background:url("http://www.tomnod.com/nod/img/icon-chevron-big-right.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -5px;
    background-size: 28px 66px;
    float: left;
}

.contentType {
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.contentType:hover {
    background-color: #1FB2E4;
    cursor: pointer;        
}
```

And here is script.js:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.Processes = ko.observableArray([
        { name: ko.observable("Scheduling Requests"), 
          contentTypes: ko.observableArray([
                { contentType: ko.observable("Test Requirement Documents") },
                { contentType: ko.observable("Flight Test Services Request") },
                { contentType: ko.observable("Schedules") }
          ])
        },
        { name: ko.observable("Planning"),
          contentTypes: ko.observableArray([
                { contentType: ko.observable("Plans") },
                { contentType: ko.observable("Data Analysis Methods") },
                { contentType: ko.observable("First Flight Readiness Review") },
                { contentType: ko.observable("Test Point Tables") },
                { contentType: ko.observable("Plans") },
                { contentType: ko.observable("Data Analysis Methods") },
                { contentType: ko.observable("First Flight Readiness Review") },
                { contentType: ko.observable("Test Point Tables") }
          ])
        },
        { name: ko.observable("Configuration Control"),
          contentTypes: ko.observableArray([
                { contentType: ko.observable("Plans") },
                { contentType: ko.observable("Data Analysis Methods") },
                { contentType: ko.observable("Test Point Tables") },
                { contentType: ko.observable("Safety Review Boards") }
          ])
        },
        { name: ko.observable("Airplane Modification"),
          contentTypes: ko.observableArray([
                { contentType: ko.observable("Plans") },
                { contentType: ko.observable("Data Analysis Methods") },
                { contentType: ko.observable("First Flight Readiness Review") },
                { contentType: ko.observable("First Flight Readiness Review") },
                { contentType: ko.observable("Test Point Tables") },
                { contentType: ko.observable("Safety Review Boards") }
          ])
        },
        { name: ko.observable("Test Execution"),
          contentTypes: ko.observableArray([
                { contentType: ko.observable("Plans") },
                { contentType: ko.observable("Data Analysis Methods") },
                { contentType: ko.observable("First Flight Readiness Review") },
                { contentType: ko.observable("Test Point Tables") },
                { contentType: ko.observable("Safety Review Boards") }
          ])
        },
        { name: ko.observable("Tracking"),
          contentTypes: ko.observableArray([
                { contentType: ko.observable("Data Analysis Methods") },
                { contentType: ko.observable("First Flight Readiness Review") },
                { contentType: ko.observable("Test Point Tables") },
                { contentType: ko.observable("Safety Review Boards") }
          ])
        },
        { name: ko.observable("Analysis Reporting"),
          contentTypes: ko.observableArray([
                { contentType: ko.observable("Plans") },
                { contentType: ko.observable("Safety Review Boards") }
          ])
        }
    ]);
}

$(function(){
    var vm = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

I've looked around and have found no one else with a similar situation.  In fact, every tutorial I've found has Knockout set up and used in the exact way I'm used to using.  I did find one library called KoSp (Knockout for SharePoint) with special SharePoint bindings, but the other tutorials seem to be getting by without it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your viewModel? Also, are you saying that if you go to the edit page and don't do anything, after some amount of time more elements are being added?

Comment: Yeah in the browser I was looking at an editor and talking to a colleague about the issue when i saw the page reevaluate and expand.  I also added the javascript code.

Comment: I think my issue was because I was putting the knockout code into a sharepoint site directly.  I've switched to making a sharepoint app and things are much better.  But if anyone knows, is the in browser site editor supposed to continually evaluate knockout code like that?